# SwiftUI zoom Map to list of POIs

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am displaying the search results as pin in MAP using below code

```
                Map(coordinateRegion: $searchResultLocation, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: searchResults) { dest in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: dest.coordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)) {
                            MapPin(coordinate)
                    }
                }
```

I like Map to zoom dynamically to the search results, how do I do that in SwiftUI

Comment: `MapPin` is deprecated (source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mappin). Try using `MapMarker`. As far as the documentation goes, I would suggest using `MapMarker` or `MapAnnotation` but not both. It would also be helpful how you initialized `$searchResultLocation`.

Comment: MapPin is my custom view,  $searchResultLocation = current location coordinate

Comment: Alright, fair enough. But how do you initialize it exactly? `init(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, span: MKCoordinateSpan)`should suffice at this point.

Comment: @mflknr yes with that init method passing the current user location as coordinate, after user search I update this coordinate value with first object lat long of the results, its kind of hacky so I need better solution